# Wcf Sync DataBase Application IIS looking into wrong path

Tags: wcf, iis-7, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

I am currently using Wcf with Sync application.

I have deployed the application in C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/DbSyncWcfService
I have deployed from path D:\MySyncService\MySyncServiceProject\MySyncService\MySyncService\DBSyncWCF.

I am successfully able to browse the application.
But when I use the WCf Application. It gives me an error as below.
DBSyncHandler :: initScopeInfo() :: Exception ==System.ServiceModel.FaultExcepti
on`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Timeout expired.  The timeout period
elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (F
ault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDe
tailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed
 prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at DBSyncWcfService.DBSyncService.InitializeScopeConfig(String xmlasstring) i
n D:\MySyncService\MySyncServiceProject\MySyncService\MySyncService\DBSyncWCF\DB
SyncService.svc.cs:line 92
   at SyncInvokeInitializeScopeConfig(Object , Object[] , Object[] )

Basically I am surprised as the path it is showing is from my physical path.

Answer (score 0):

that's debugging information embedded in your application. the path is when you compiled your app. the deployment path of your wcf service has nothing to do with that.